# Android how to get the fault code

Tags: android

I am hitting a `webservice` which returns me a list when the parameters passed are correct.
When the parameters passed are incorrect it returns a fault code.How to get this fault code?
I have used a Sax Listner which gives three methods.

```
public void parsingSuccess(List list),

public void parsingError(String error) &

public void connectionError(String error)
```

in case of parsing error i dont get a list.How to get the fault code in such a case.
I am using ASYnc task. i do in background i parsing the url. The response comes in the form of an xml

Comment: what do you mean by **fault code**?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a Response from your server as an `Entity`, you can do the following:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

if (statusCode == 200) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I am using ASYnc task. i do in background i parsing the url. The response comes in the form of an xml

Comment: the async task is not much of an issue here. Just prevents your application from being locked until the response arrives. May you can post some code on how you get the response?

Comment: parse the url in the doinbackground msgList=SaxEngine.instance.parse(populated values,url,activity name); if the response contains a success message the populate db in the onPostexecute method. incase of error since we get just the error message we just display that